# Token doesn't show in MetaMask

Tags: metamask

I bought some ICON (ICX) tokens on Binance, then transferred them to MetaMask. I still see the transaction on Etherscan.  Initially, the tokens showed in MetaMask (tokens held went from 8 to 9), but the # of tokens was an odd number.  I checked MetaMask the next day and the number of tokens is back to 8 with no sign of the ICX coins.  If click on Add Token and I copy in the contract address, the token name says "Like ETH", precision says 0.  Where are those tokens?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked https://etherscan.io/ using your account address, and see if the tokens appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this problem many times with Metamask , go to Tokens tab and try to Add Token  and check again , it should show the balance of icx tokens in metamask :

Contract address : 0xb5a5f22694352c15b00323844ad545abb2b11028

Symbol : ICX

Decimal of Precision : 18